# Redux - How change state in store permanetlny?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with save the state after change by action from external component in my app. This may be a reducer's fault?

```
const loginReducer = (state={},action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_STATUS_TRUE':
    console.log(state);
    return {...state, showLogin: true}
    case 'CHANGE_STATUS_FALSE':
    console.log(state);
    return {...state, showLogin: false}
    default:

    return state;
  }
}

export const store = createStore(loginReducer, {showLogin: false});
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the symptoms are?

Comment: I have component i.a. with button which trigger mapDispatchToProps and it's work. When I go to another component in my app, the state returns to its initial state. For example: I'm in page with login form - state change for true - next I'm going to page with profile information - in this moment status returns to false.

Comment: How are you "going to page"?  Are you using something like React-Router?

Comment: Yes, I'm using React-Router. https://gist.github.com/D3AR316/b455725ec700e76d4945c54a0e1dc710

Comment: can you add some more code to the gist ? Like where are you dispatching (looks like it's in `changeStatusLogin`, but couldn't find it), your action creators, etc.

Comment: @Dane i found where was the problem. My routes don't contain properly navbar component, so every time when I changed the "pages-component", my application was reloaded.